# Selenium RemoteWebDriver memory issues

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, selenium, webdriver

I'm running a Selenium Standalone Server, version 2.25.0

I run a program in c# executing the driver by:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit();
capabilities.IsJavaScriptEnabled = false;
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Then I collect some information via `driver.FindElement(By.)`.

everything works fine.

After i executed all

I quit the driver by:

```
driver.Quit();
```

The test works fine. But when I take a look into the task-manager while executing I can see "java.exe" (the selenium server) grabbing memory and afterwards not releasing it.

How can i solve this problem? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

hmm....
comparing to my code:

```
public class BaseSeleniumTest extends SeleneseTestBase {
    static WebDriver driver;



    @BeforeClass
    public static void firefoxSetUp() throws MalformedURLException {

          DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();


        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.4.52:4444/wd/hub"), capability);




        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
    }
    @Before
    public void homePageRefresh() throws IOException {
        driver.get("login.base.url");
    }


    @AfterClass
    public static void closeFirefox(){
        driver.quit();
    }

.....
}
```

I do not have such memory issue. Grabbed memory was released. Could you provide the way you declare and initialize (creating instance) *driver*  ?

[image]

Investigated a lil bit more:
**HtmlUnit appears to be leaking memory; what's the deal?**
Make sure *(a) that you are using the latest version of HtmlUnit*, and *(b) that you are calling `WebClient.closeAllWindows()` when you are finished with your WebClient instance*.

Taken from [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#MemoryLeak)

Comment: Hey, you Code is Java isn't it? Well if im doing simple operations I don't have memory issues. But im Checking Several Links ond while crawling my site. My process java.exe is grown to 1.5 gigs ram...

Comment: yep. I'm using selenium+java.
hmmm... seems very tricky issue(
updated post with screen...

Comment: Well I discovered, when I'm using a browser instead of the HtmlUnit I don't get the problem because the reserved RAM from the browser grows but in the end it gets closed correctly so it takes no effect on java.exe.

Comment: I create the Driver and I closed and quit it. I'm using the latest Version of selenium for c# . So I only can open the RemoteWebdriver and close this driver in the end. I think you mixing two different ways? Im using the HtmlUnit build in the Selenium. There are the only options: close or quit.

Comment: hmm... 
look through this set of issue. Suppose it be interesting to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535243/htmlunit-is-throwing-out-of-memory-and-maybe-leaking-memory
http://www.seleniumwebdriver.com/google-selenium-webdriver/memory-leak-with-htmlunit-and-javascript-enabled/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059773/htmlunit-selenium-within-production

Comment: I'm using webdriver + java in my daily practice. But IMHO HtmlUnit somhow cause your memory leak issue

Comment: IMHO too. But now tell me how can i close the driver correctly. I guess its because after a test a brwoser gets closed but not the server? When I'm running HtmlUnit its running directly via the server. But how to solve it? When i try to start the server again I'm getting heap mem errors :/. I'm using Webdriver too, but using it with the built in Remotewebdriver starting a HtmlUnit instead of an ff test.