# Retrieving a complete webpage including dynamically loaded links/images

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, wget, httrack

**Problem**

Downloading a complete working offline copy of a website that loads links/images dynamically

**Research**

There are questions (e.g. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348289/download-a-working-local-copy-of-a-webpage), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000468/how-to-download-links-in-the-html-of-a-url?noredirect=1&lq=1), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706934/download-an-offline-version-of-a-webpage?noredirect=1&lq=1)) on Stackoverflow addressing this issue, most of which have the top answers using [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [httrack](https://www.httrack.com/), both of which fail miserably (please do correct me if I am wrong) on pages that dyanmically load links or uses `srcset` instead of `src` for `img` tag -or anything loaded via JS-. A rather obvious solution was [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/), however, if you ever used Selenium in production, you quickly start seeing the issues that arise from such a decision (resource heavy, quite complex to use head-full driver, the fact that is it not built for that), that being said, [there are people claiming to have been using it easily in production for years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059773/htmlunit-selenium-within-production)

**Expected Solution**

A script (preferably in python), that parses the page for links and loads them separately. I cannot seem to find any existing scripts that do that. If your solution is "so implement your own", then it is pointless to be asking the question in the first place, I am seeking an existing implementation.

**Examples**

1. Shopify.com
2. Websites built using Wix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there are head-less versions of `Selenium` and alternatives such as `PhantomJS`, either can be used with a small script to scrape any dynamically loaded website.

I had implemented a generic scraper [here](https://github.com/naderalexan/generic_scrapper), and explained more about the topic [here](https://medium.com/dreidev/web-scraping-in-python-e07fba0a1663)

Comment: well now you'd use puppeteer as it actually can even handle running with javascript

Comment: Links dead. FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means throw things away like rubbish :-(